# Task Scheduler not excuting task

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, shutdown, scheduled-tasks

I made a batch file that creates an auto shutdown task in taskschd.msc which is supposed to shutdown the computer at a certain hour each day.

The said batch:

```
@echo off
SCHTASKS /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Auto Shutdown" /ST 20:00:00 /TR "C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /s /f /t 000"
```

In some of the machines i deployed the batch file the shutdown was successful while in others i got the following error message and the machine did not turn off.

> The Task Scheduler can not start the "Auto Shutdown" task for the user "LOCAL \ admin". Additional data: error value: 2147943645.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

Comment: Is `run with highest privileges` checked? This is required on some systems.

Comment: It's not, is there a way to add that feature the batch file?

Comment: @Minnen yes, you have to pass a username and password in like this, along with the `/rl highest` flag. `SCHTASKS /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU username /RP password /RL HIGHEST`